# Is there a way to change the navigation bar tint color in the more navigation edit popup modal?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am able to change the tint color of more using `self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor`, but when tapping the `Edit`, it brings up a modal popup. How to change the tint color of that modal dialog?

Comment: Use the appearance proxy so all navbars get the same color without needs to individually set each one.

Comment: rmaddy: Thank you, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using

```
let appearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
appearance.barTintColor = Constants.Color.barTint // UIColor
appearance.tintColor = .white
```